# PHP 1st while loop's output result as 2nd while loop's variable for query

Tags: php, mysql

**Question 1: Is it possible to feed 1st while loop's output result as 2nd while loop's variable for query?**

I have mySQL table "reorder_in_process" below:

```
(`id`, `item`, `to_order`, `cat_no`, `supplier`) VALUES
(48, 'Petri Dish', 62, 1006, 'Progressive'),
(47, 'Beaker', 46, 1005, 'Progressive'),
(46, 'Tissue', 17, 1008, 'Needpoint'),
(45, 'Pipet', 77, 1004, 'Kumpulan');
```

And my php below:

```
<?PHP
include ('db.php');
$sql4 = "SELECT DISTINCT supplier FROM reorder_in_process";
$result4 = mysqli_query($con,$sql4);
$supplier4 = $row4['supplier'];
$i=0;

while($row4 = mysqli_fetch_array($result4)){
echo "<h4>".$row4['supplier']."</h4>";

echo  "<div><table><tr>
                        <th>No</th>
                        <th>Item</th>
                        <th>Cat. No</th>                                            
                        <th>Buy QTY</th>
                        <th>Supplier</th>                   
                    </tr>";
$sql5 = "SELECT * FROM reorder_in_process WHERE supplier=$supplier4";
$result5 = mysqli_query($con,$sql5);
while($row5 = mysqli_fetch_array($result5)) {
$i++;
    echo "<tr>
            <td>".$i. "</td>
           <td>".$row5['item']."</td>
           <td>".$row5['cat_no']."</td>
           <td>".$row5['to_order']."</td>
           <td>".$row5['supplier']."</td>      
     </tr>";
}
echo "</table></div>";
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I doesn't work...I want the output result like below:

```
Progressive
No  Item    Cat. No Buy QTY Supplier
1   Petri Dish  1006    62  Progressive
2   Beaker      1005    46  Progressive

Needpoint
No  Item    Cat. No Buy QTY Supplier
1   Tissue  1008    17  Needpoint

Kumpulan
No  Item    Cat. No Buy QTY Supplier
1   Pipet   1004    77  Kumpulan
```

Pls help to find my mistake and solution to it. Thanks.

Comment: string should be enclosed by single quotes "...supplier='$supplier4'"

Comment: I tried tat......"supplier='$supplier4'", not working...

Comment: you need to pass the each supplier change the query like this  "...supplier='$row4['supplier']'"   @p. Lau

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the below line is undefined because it's outside of the while loop

```
 $supplier4 = $row4['supplier'];
```

Push the above code into inside first while loop and string should be enclosed by single quotes like this

```
 "...supplier='$supplier4'"
```

you need to reset the `$i=1` for each new supplier

**Update 1:**

```
<?PHP
include ('db.php');
$sql4 = "SELECT DISTINCT supplier FROM reorder_in_process";
$result4 = mysqli_query($con,$sql4);

while($row4 = mysqli_fetch_array($result4)){

    $i=1;
    $supplier4 = $row4['supplier'];

    echo "<h4>".$row4['supplier']."</h4>";

    echo  "<div><table><tr>
                            <th>No</th>
                            <th>Item</th>
                            <th>Cat. No</th>                                            
                            <th>Buy QTY</th>
                            <th>Supplier</th>                   
                       </tr>";

    $sql5 = "SELECT * FROM reorder_in_process WHERE supplier='$supplier4'";
    $result5 = mysqli_query($con,$sql5);
    while($row5 = mysqli_fetch_array($result5)) {

        echo "<tr>
                <td>".$i. "</td>
               <td>".$row5['item']."</td>
               <td>".$row5['cat_no']."</td>
               <td>".$row5['to_order']."</td>
               <td>".$row5['supplier']."</td>      
         </tr>";

         $i++;
    }
    echo "</table></div>";
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Yes! Tat works, but.....the number(No) is 1,2,3,4. It has to be 1,2,1,1.

Comment: yes you need to reset the $i=1 for each new supplier . check my update1 @P.Lau

Comment: I solve it myself oredi! Yes!! Thanks guys...u save my day and push me forward!

Comment: if my answer is useful mark it with green tick it's useful for future user reference  @P.Lau

Comment: I solve that numbering (No) by putting $i=0 below $sql5 = "SELECT * FROM reorder_in_process WHERE supplier='$supplier4'";

Comment: You don't need to query the same table twice, the information you want to group it by is already available. A single query can do the job, with some added logic in PHP.

Comment: @P.Lau both is do same job only .we need to reset the $i=1 for each new supplier . before second while also fine .

Comment: Both end up with the same result, but there's no reason why you would query the database more than you need to. A query within a loop is a **bad idea** - this current code will generate 4 queries to the DB (and more when additional data gets added), where as the suggestion in my answer only queries the DB *once*.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to run two queries like that.

Instead of performing one query, just to query the *same* table again inside the loop, modify your structure such that you just query the table once. Just `ORDER BY supplier` and check if the current rows supplier differs from the last rows supplier. (Disclosure: I haven't fully tested this logic, it might need some tweaking).

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM reorder_in_process ORDER BY supplier");
$first_iteration = true;
$current_supplier = null;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    // If a new supplier is encountered, close the first table (if its no the first iteration) and add new header + start new table 
    if ($row['supplier'] != $current_supplier) {
        if ($first_iteration == false)
            echo "</table></div>";

        $i = 1;
        $first_iteration = false;
        $current_supplier = $row['supplier'];
        echo "<h4>".$row['supplier']."</h4>";
        echo  "<div><table><tr>
                    <th>No</th>
                    <th>Item</th>
                    <th>Cat. No</th>                                            
                    <th>Buy QTY</th>
                    <th>Supplier</th>                   
                </tr>";
    }

    echo "<tr>
                <td>".$i. "</td>
               <td>".$row['item']."</td>
               <td>".$row['cat_no']."</td>
               <td>".$row['to_order']."</td>
               <td>".$row['supplier']."</td>      
         </tr>";
    $i++;
}
echo "</table></div>";
```

Comment: My table may grow big in future, will tis code run faster than my double query loop?

Comment: Yes, this is a better approach - because running a query inside another query like that is bad practice. Instead of having 1 query, you end up with 4++ queries (and that can get to 10 queries if you have 9 different suppliers). You should avoid query inside another query when you can, and with a simple adjustment, you can easily avoid it, like shown above.

Comment: Ya it works 2! Thanks man! I am quite new to PHP so the only way I know is to loop within loop. Now I have more choice. I will use this when table grows.

Comment: if you think that this is a better answer(I certainly do), change the accepted answer

Comment: I agree the answer from  @Qirel is better approach and I will surely use his approach, but the 1st suggestion is answering correctly to my question : Is it possible to feed 1st while loop's output result as 2nd while loop's variable for query? So I leave it tat way.